# Installing package from Gitlab

Tags: r

I am trying to install the shinybiomod package from: https://gitlab.com/IanOndo/shinybiomod I install devtools first and call the library

`library (devtools) devtools::install_gitlab("IanOndo/ShinyBIOMOD")`

i get this error: Downloading GitLab repo IanOndo/ShinyBIOMOD@HEAD from URL https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/14018346/repository/archive.tar.gz?sha=HEAD Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet, : download from 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/14018346/repository/archive.tar.gz?sha=HEAD' failed

I download it and try to install it manually and I get this:

Error: 22:1: unexpected '}' 22: } ^ Execution halted Warning message: In install.packages(files[tarballs], .libPaths()[1L], repos = NULL, : installation of package ‘C:/Users/lenovo/Downloads/shinybiomod-master.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

What can I do to solve it? Thank you

Get a solution or an alternative to fix the error

Comment: That package likely depends on _other_ packages and your error most likely comes from those. Also note that installing from git(hub|lab) is installing from _source_ so you may need to install Rtools and all that jazz.

Comment: Ty, I have Rtools, devtools, source and the other packages installed. But still I keep getting this error:   Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitLab:
  cannot open URL 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/IanOndo%2FShinyBIOMOD/repository/files/DESCRIPTION/raw?ref=HEAD'
please , Can you check if it works for you?

Comment: I would suggest to look at the DESCRIPTION file of the target package and ensure you have all dependencies.  Then install just the package.  Maybe even by cloning the repo / getting a tar.gz and running `R CMD INSTALL ...` on the tarball to get best diagnostocs.

Comment: Frankly, that package `Imports` 40 (!) packages and `Remotes` 4 more. To find if/where there is a problem would take stepping through each of them, so I suggest ... package by package, confirm you have it or try to install it manually. Once all imports are verified "installed", try `remotes::install_*` the remote packages. It's a bit laborious, but if you really need that package, perhaps _this is the way_.